# Debugging SSL connection termination issue

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, networking, .net-6.0, mtls

I've a ASP.NET core web application that uses built in kestrel server and configurations to setup a https connection. Here's how the configutarion (settings.json) looks like

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
        }
      },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
          "Subject": "localhost", //default cert generated by visual studio 
          "Store": "My",
          "Location": "LocalMachine",
          "AllowInvalid": "true"
                }
                  }
              }
}
```

The server expectes a client certificate

```
.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
    {
        // certificate is an X509Certificate2
        o.ServerCertificate = cert;
        o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
    });
 
}).UseUrls($"https://*:{int.Parse(Configuration["Port"])}")
```

This is the error trace

```
    Unable to retrieve products from https://localhost:5001/api/Products. Exception: 
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
```

I'm pretty sure the configuration looks fine and it might be an external thing that is terminating the SSL connection like windows defender firewall because it works in a different system. Can I get some suggestions to identify the factor that might close the connection before SSL connection is established?

Comment: Have you checked if the certificate is actually installed?

Comment: @GuruStron then it won't start the server, right? it will say it can't find the cert?

Comment: Why is mtls tagged on your post? There is nothing in your post related to mTLS.

Comment: @JohnHanley The server expects a client certificate for mutual authentication.

Comment: You did not show mTLS usage or explanation when you posted the question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I suspected that the mTLS might have a role but since there was no strong evidince I didn't highligh it. The code expects mTLS and I've modified the post to include that as well.

Comment: For HTTP mTLS problems, I use the CLI `curl` which supports client certificates. Use debug mode to see the TLS layer exchanges. Another excellent tool for debugging mTLS is WireShark.

Answer (score 0):

Kestrel uses TLS version 1.1 or 1.2 by default. You could try to enable higher version by configure the program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.OnAuthenticate = (context, sslOptions) =>
        {
            sslOptions.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
        };
    });
});
```

Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-default-supported-tls-protocol-versions-changed#recommended-action